# how to combine two vars in javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables

i am trying to create dynamic textboxes. The textbox should be created only if the previous textbox is non-empty. So far i have done this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
var i=0;
function myFunction()
{

var box = document.createElement("input");
box.type = "text";

var str=box+i;
if(i==0)
{
 document.body.appendChild(box);
}
else if(document.getElementById('str').value!=0)
{ 
 document.body.appendChild(box);  
}

i++;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" id="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Show box" />
</body>
</html>
```

but str is not recognised as element id. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to do? There's no element on your page with ID `str` and you're not assigning IDs to any elements you create. Also, both branches of your if statement are doing the same thing.

Comment: box is a reference to a dom element, not a string.

Comment: str='box'+i; is closer to what you seek i guess

Answer (score 1):

```
var i = 0;

function myFunction() {
    var lastInput = document.getElementById('box' + i);
    if (!lastInput) {
        // always put first input 
        document.body.appendChild(createInput(0));
    } else if (lastInput.value != 0) {
        // append another one only if previous input content is non-null
      i++;
      document.body.appendChild(createInput(i));
    }

}

function createInput(i) {
    var box = document.createElement("input");
    box.type = 'text';
    box.id = 'box' + i;
    box.value = 0;
  return box;
}
```

Comment: yeah, its working. Thank you. well,i managed to fix my code also.. :)

Comment: Ok, all the best ! so put my anwswer as accepted, and if your final solution is significatively different, edit your post to add the solution you came to. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Your wrongs:

1. `str = 'box' + i;`
2. Forget to assign `box.id = str`
3. Use `getElementById(str)` instead of `getElementById('str')`